# Помощь. Python, настройка погоды через OpenWeatherMap

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, openweathermap

Я делаю бота в вк, который умеет выводить погоду. Но если пользователь введет не название города, а например: "аашопшоапвшап", то бот **умрёт**. Хотел реализовать через список доступных городов, т.е. что бы бот проверял есть ли название в списке. Если есть идёт дальше по коду, если нет, пишет, что он не занет такого города и просит ввести еще раз. Но проблема в том, что списка доступных городов я не нашёл. А к примеру город Бразилиа, сайт не знает и не выдаёт погоду. **Помогите пожалуйста**

```
def temperature(id, text):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id': id, 'message': text, 'random_id': 0})
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            if event.to_me:
                msg = event.text.lower()
                id = event.user_id
                city = msg
                cities = ['']
                owm = pyowm.OWM(мой токен на сайте)
                mgr = owm.weather_manager()
                observation = mgr.weather_at_place(city)
                weather = observation.weather
                sender(id, weather.temperature('celsius')['temp'])
                break
```

Comment: проверяйте, что в observation, если ошибка - уведомьте пользователя про несуществующее название города

Answer (score 0):

```
try: 
    "ваш код"
except:
    "ваш код когда ввёл чтото не так"
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]